# How to convert a stack of medical images from the work space into .png without losing information in a specific folder?

Tags: image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, image-conversion, medical

I have medical images of 130 patients in a folder which includes two types of files for each patient. For example, `patient1.mhd` and `patient1.raw`files. I downloaded [Matlab FileExchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29344-read-medical-data-3d) to read these files. But I have to import each patients' files manually from the menu.

I want to save each stack of data into .png files for each patient. For instance, patient1 data has 3D matrix (281x389x104, (i.e., 104 images, Width: 281 and Height: 389)), and I want to save all patients' files in one folder with `png` or `any other image e.g. jpg` format without losing original information. What do you suggest? Does anyone know any function or code that helps me?

Your help is appreciated

Many thanks

Comment: I would look into building a custom chunk for the PNG which could hold all the original information. The PNG could also be produced as a Animation PNG (APNG) where each image in the stack is saved as animation frame. Software that doesn't support animation would still be able to show the first image. You would also need to have a reader that can extract the chunk when you need the original data.

Comment: @K3N thanks for the reply. I saved a stack of one patient in a folder including all slices (with .mat format), this means that I have now 104 mat files. I tried to convert into jpg fro [the code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/262831-how-to-convert-file-mat-to-jpg). But it gives white images. What do you suggest?

Comment: You didn't state what OS you use.

Comment: Is the problem to move `patient1*` to one folder and `patient2*` to another folder? Or something else?

Comment: Why do you think copying files from one folder to another will somehow lose information in the original files? Surely they will still be wherever they used to be after you finish copying/unpacking them?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you very much for your reply. The OS is windows. The problem is that I have to manually convert each patient data. I would like to automate reading `.mhd` and `.raw` files for each patient. 
I do not think copying will lose the data. My concern is the conversion from was format to image formats (such as 'jpg` or `png`) will result in losing data.

Comment: @MarkSetchell all files are in one folder and I want to read the `mhd` and `raw` files automatically patient by patient and then convert into `png` for each patient with different names.